# what is the s Spring 6.0.11 module compatible not working on tomcat 10

Tags: spring-mvc-test

I have migrated my Spring 4.2.4 version to Spring 6.0.11 version. I am trying to execute it on tomcat 10.But i am getting the follow exception.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is in unnamed module. As per spring framework we can run spring6 on tomcat 10 since they had implemented some jakarta implementation on spring 6.x version.can help me out on this please.

SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/SpringMVCPagination] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @53bd8fca; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @7eda2dbb)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:805)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)

Comment: It sounds you have Spring 5 or older on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, it works after changed build path jar to 6.0.11. However I am facing some issue with tiles3. Spring 6.0.0 doesn't support Apache Tiles?

Comment: Unlikely, Apache Tiles is a retired project and hasn't seen a release since 2016, which means it is probably Java EE 8 or earlier, using the `javax.*` package namespace instead of the `jakarta.*` namespace of Jakarta EE 9 or higher which is used by Spring 6.